# Select values (not from a table) not contained in an SQLite table

Tags: sqlite

In my Windows Phone 8.1 App I have an SQLite table in which every file contained in the folder Camera Roll is inserted after a periodic scan. I would like to understand, given the list of all the files in Camera Roll (provided from the4 OS), which one has not already been inserted in the table. I'm using the file path as unique identifier for every record, so the question is:

Is there a query to find what file paths (not contained in a table, just a strings list in memory) are not contained in the files table? Should I create a table to contain the files paths I have in memory? Should I use some temporary structure instead?

Answer (score 0):

If your files are sorted, or have same other kind of index, you could loop over the 'old' files from the database, and for each one, mark the corresponding 'new' one, if it exists. The remaining ones are really new.

If the database has an index, you could loop over the 'new' files, and for each one, check if it is in the 'old' table in the database.

If you want to do everything in the database, you could create a temporary table with all your in-memory files.
Comparing the two tables ends up being a single SQL query, but actually creating the temporary table might not be very efficient.